# Issue with Speck cipher on Arduino UNO

Tags: arduino-uno

I found a library for the Speck cipher here: https://github.com/Chien-Ning/ArduinoCrypto

And I'm trying to use but haven't had much luck. My code is the following:

```
#include <SPECK_AVR.h>
#include <SPECK_spec.h>

#include "SPECK_AVR.h"

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

  SpeckTxtLen = 32;
  SpeckKeyLen = 64;
  speckTxtKey[]= 0x65, 0x74, 0x69, 0x4c, 0x19, 0x18, 0x11, 0x10, 0x09, 0x08, 0x01, 0x00;

  speckKey();
  speckEnc();

  Serial.println("");
  for (int i = 0; i < SpeckTxtLen/8; i++){
  Serial.print(speckTxtKey[i], HEX);
  Serial.print(", ");
  }
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

and

```
error: expected primary-expression before ']' token
```

Do you think I'm missing something in the usage of this library?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
speckTxtKey[]= 0x65, 0x74, 0x69, 0x4c, 0x19, 0x18, 0x11, 0x10, 0x09, 0x08, 0x01, 0x00;
```

That's not how you assign an array.
And you never defined a type for the array.

It sould be:

```
byte speckTxtKey[] = {0x65, 0x74, 0x69, 0x4c, 0x19, 0x18, 0x11, 0x10, 0x09, 0x08, 0x01, 0x00};
```

**EDIT**:

I checked the source of the library to figure out how to use it, but it doesn't seem the library is meant for actual use.

`SpeckTxtLen` and `SpeckKeyLen` are macros inside *SPECK_AVR.h*, which are supposed to be changed there, not in your code.

The library also defines `speckTxtKey` inside *SPECKenc_AVR.cpp* with predefined test data based on the chosen length.

This library looks like a test implementation of the speck cipher, which was just dumped onto GitHub.

Comment: Thanks, I got rid of my error with this, but now I'm getting others, but I think it's related to the library. Should I post another question with respect to them?

Comment: False alarm, I'm still getting the "error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment". The other error is gone, but still with the one I mentioned.

Comment: @LuzA I now checked the source code of the library and it doesn't look like it's meant to be used for arbitrary data without modifications.

Comment: so I need to change the key and everything directly into the .h and .cpp files?